# Preencher um multiline-textbox com todos os itens da lista de uma combobox

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, combobox

E ai pessoal tudo bem ?

Como consigo
Preencher um textbox com todos os itens da lista de uma combobox em uma textbox , sendo que os itens da combobox podem ser variáveis vem de lugares diferentes.

[image]

Ficou assim 
[image]

Código :

```
 For Each Linha In objClasse.atividades_secundarias

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Linha.code + " - " + Linha.text)

        For Each VARIAVEL_DE_STRING As String In ComboBox1.Items
            txt_atividades_secundarias_encontradas.Text &= VARIAVEL_DE_STRING & vbCrLf
        Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução:

```
For Each VARIAVEL_DE_STRING As String In ComboBox1.Items
    txt_atividades_secundarias_encontradas.Text &= VARIAVEL_DE_STRING & vbCrLf
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each item As String In ComboBox1.Items
    TextBox1.AppendText(item + Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

Ou usando StringBuilder

```
Dim text = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

For Each item As String In ComboBox1.Items
    text.AppendLine(item)
Next

TextBox1.AppendText(text.ToString())
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos que ajudaram porque eu tomei penalidade -3 no post ?
Não entendi isso .